# Transfer a file from a website to a server

Tags: file-transfer

I want to transfer a few files from a website to a ftp server over the internet (bypassing my computer). Im guessing php is the best languaje to use, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what the server lets you run. PHP does the job: http://radinks.net/ftp/php/

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the website server?  If so, cpanel has a sweet built in transfer/backup utility that could send the whole directory to another server, including your ftp server.